# NoMoreRecordText property is not working with the List-Paging plugin on Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am using this plugin in my application and I am having the next problem:

When I am scrolling-down in the device I send a new request and I am receiving a new array with other list, the problem comes when array is empty, (It means I haven´t more data) the message in the bottom is "Load more ...." instead of "No more.." for instance... 
I don´t understand the problem... maybe it doesn´t detect the "end" .. help please!

Code in the view is simple:

```
//LISTPAGING
        {
            xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
            autoPaging: true,
            loadMoreText : 'Loading more..',
            noMoreRecordsText : 'All loaded'
        }
```

Code from the proxy:

```
reader: {
                totalProperty: "total",
                rootProperty: "activities"
        },
```

Any clue??

Comment: Are you getting 'total' in your response data?

Comment: Maybe Should I add a new field with the total amount in the json??

Comment: Are you handling the backend also? In the json data there should be one field "total". copy paste your store proxy here.

Comment: I am trying to read the "total" from the json response and evaluate this condition..  can you copy an example??  thanks!

Comment: I have edited the code adding the "proxy-code" from the reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!!

Problem was coming with the TOTAL parameter from the backend, in my case the TOTAL was evaluated for each request, instead of items total..

CLOSED  Roger and over !   :-)